22.04 LTS failed upgrade to 24.04 and now missing packages and only boots to command line
I don't usually trust the distribution upgrades having had less than a 50% success rate in the past but this was a recent clean installation of 22.04 following a disk crash. The upgrade failed but the system was still functional and booted without errors, so I just accepted than I had to stay with 22.04. However, I recently tried installing sendemail and that triggered a host of errors.screen photo
It now boots to the command line but I can no longer access it with SSH.
I've tried updating with --fix-broken and --fix-package but just get a lot of errors.
I'm puzzled because this is basically a clean install. It runs git, web-server, HA (in a snap) and a few other apps but nothing special.
Is there a simple way to fix this? When it's happend in the past (with other machines), I've just abandonned it and done a fresh install on a new disk. I don't have any spare disks right now and I'd like to get it semi-functional at least as it's my main file server.

From the error in your screenshot it looks like a problem with DNS not being able to resolve the hostnames of archive machines. No apt commands will likely work until you get past that issue. Once you resolve the issue with DNS (network, nameserver configuration or whatever it is), you may be able to use apt again.

That's certainly part of the problem. I've been using ChatGPT to debug the issue using recovery mode and I've made some progress. It seems almost every package is broken. Once I fixed the ethernet (which had been disabled) and the DNS issue, an apt update did 100s of Mbytes of updates.
I can get it into a state where it boots to the command line. The desktop is broken despite an unintall/install. I'm currently getting an error with dbus. All the symlinks appear to be ok but it's saying the link has been severed. ChatGPT is now adsiving a fresh install.

if you can login, and have network access then sudo apt update followed by sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^ (the caret ^ is important) will almost certainly fix it.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop but I think there's a more serious problem with dbus. As I understand it, dbus is the Ubuntu ipc mechanism so pretty fundamental.
I've given up trying to fix this installation. I'm sure it could be done but it's quicker to copy over everything I need and do a fresh install of 24.04. That's not going too well either, some quite serious problems with the installer. I'll put them in a separate post.
Thanks for your help though.
